# Selenium Firefox IDE to JAVA code as parametrizated

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

I want to prepare a selenium test as parametrizated. I've researched about parameterization with Selenium Firefox IDE. There is no problem about that. It uses a JS file and so on. But when I export it as Java code as Junit, getting value from js file as parameter doesn't work.

Here are selenium HTML and exported Java code;

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://www.google.com.tr/" />
<title>Parameterization_Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">New Test</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>email</td>
    <td>email</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>password</td>
    <td>password</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=gbi4t</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=Email</td>
    <td>${email}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=Passwd</td>
    <td>${password}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=signIn</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

```java
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestCase;
import org.junit.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class SeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestCase {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/home/ahmet/Desktop/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseUrl = "http://www.google.com.tr";
        selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void testU() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
        String email = selenium.getEval("email");
        String password = selenium.getEval("password");
        selenium.click("id=gbi4t");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("id=Email", email);
        selenium.type("id=Passwd", password);
        selenium.click("id=signIn");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }


}
```

When it tries to get value with `getEval` function,`SeleniumException` is occured.

Is there a way to provide parameterization for Java code which is generated from Selenium Firefox IDE directly?

Note: The code is updated a bit just to work with ChromeDriver.

Answer (score 0):

Create SelectItem.java file with following code.

```
public class SelectItem {

    private String label;
    private String value;


    public SelectItem(String label, String value) { 
        this.label = label; 
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

then Create SeleniumTest.java file and add following code in @Test section.

```
@Test
public void testU() throws Exception
{
java.util.List<SelectItem> selectItems = new java.util.ArrayList<SelectItem>();
selectItems.add(new SelectItem("Email1","Password1"));
selectItems.add(new SelectItem("Email2","Password2"));

for(SelectItem selItem:selectItems)
{
String user = selItem.getLabel();
String password = selItem.getValue();
selenium.click("id=gbi4t");
selenium.type("id=Email", email);
selenium.type("id=Passwd", password);
selenium.click("id=signIn");
}
}
```